# Fluent-bit inside Spark Container

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, splunk, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am trying to run `fluent-bit` inside `spark` container so that `spark driver container` which is writing the logs in a file `/var/log/sparkDriver.log` controlled by `spark log4j` properties, can be read or consumed by `fluent-bit`. I know that running multiple processes in one container is an AntiParttern but right now I have no choice. What configuration I need, to **read** this file (`/var/log/sparkDriver.log`) and forward the logs to our internal `splunk hec` server.

I know `fluent-bit` can be used as a `sidecar` in the pod but I am using simple `spark-submit` to submit my spark job to `K8S` and `spark-submit` doesn't have any way to tell `k8s` that I want to run a sidecar (fluent-bit) as well.

I also know that `fluent-bit` can installed as deamonSet in the cluster which will basically run on each node in the `k8s` cluster and forward logs from the container via node to `Splunk`. But this option is also not going to work for me.

So I thought if I could bake `fluent-bit` or `splunkforwarder` or even `fluentd` and read the logs from a file or **stdout**. I know that the other 2 options will inflate my `spark` docker image but I don't have an option right now.

Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated

I actually tried the `tail` and `splunk` but somehow I am not able to figure out the right configuration for `fluent-bit`

Here is my log file which is `spark` logs using `log4j`:

I actually tried it but somehow I am not able to put the right configuration around it. Here is how my log files look:

```
20/03/02 19:35:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 12526.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 12526, 172.16.7.233, executor 1, partition 12526, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7885 bytes)
20/03/02 19:35:47 DEBUG KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: Launching task 12526 on executor id: 1 hostname: 172.16.7.233.
20/03/02 19:35:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 12524.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 12524) in 1 ms on 172.16.7.233 (executor 1) (12525/1000000)
20/03/02 19:35:47 TRACE MessageDecoder: Received message OneWayMessage: OneWayMessage{body=NettyManagedBuffer{buf=CompositeByteBuf(ridx: 5, widx: 1622, cap: 1622, components=2)}}
20/03/02 19:35:47 TRACE MessageDecoder: Received message OneWayMessage: OneWayMessage{body=NettyManagedBuffer{buf=PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 13, widx: 1630, cap: 32768)}}
20/03/02 19:35:47 TRACE MessageDecoder: Received message OneWayMessage: OneWayMessage{body=NettyManagedBuffer{buf=PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 13, widx: 2414, cap: 4096)}}
```

Here is my `fluent-bit` configuration:

```
[INPUT]
    Name  tail
    Path  /var/log/sparklog.log

# nest the record under the 'event' key
[FILTER]
    Name nest
    Match *
    Operation nest
    Wildcard *
    Nest_under event

# add event metadata
[FILTER]
    Name      modify
    Match     *
    Add index myindex
    Add host  ${HOSTNAME}
    Add app_name ${APP_NAME}
    Add namespace ${NAMESPACE}

[OUTPUT]
    Name        Splunk
    Match       *
    Host        splunk.example.com
    Port        30000
    Splunk_Token XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
    Splunk_Send_Raw On
    TLS         On
    TLS.Verify  Off
```

Comment: Curious why deamonSet doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Tail https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/input/tail and splunk plugin https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/output/splunk should do the trick for you.

Are you facing any specific issue with configuring these two?